# No managed objects able to see after lightweight migration

Tags: ios, core-data, core-data-migration

Created a new model because attribute were added to an entity, and a parent entity were removed. And afterwards with new model from DB no managed object is able to load in. If I switch back to old DB I am able to see managed objects. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Forget to add: `NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption`, `NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption`.

Now it persistent store loading looks like:

```
var error: NSError?
do {
    try coordinatorMain.addPersistentStoreWithType(NSSQLiteStoreType, configuration: nil, URL: mainDB, options: [NSSQLitePragmasOption: ["journal_mode" : "DELETE"], NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption: true, NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption: true])
} catch var error1 as NSError {
    error = error1
}
```